# Cypress - wait for next button to reappear before going on

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I have a cart preview button on the top right of the screen.
If I click this button, a div appears. This div lists items in the cart, and below each item there is a "remove" button.

I need to click on every "remove" button of this div, and remove all the items one by one.

The problem is that after I click "remove" a spinner appears for some seconds. When the spinner disappears, appear the rest of the items and the rest of the "remove" buttons.

```
  cy.get('.cart-toggle-btn').click()
  cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').each(aaa => {
    aaa.click()
  })
```

If I use the code above, it only removes the first item, and then the test passes. But there are still other items in the cart.

How can I "tell" cypress to wait for the redux dispatch action to complete (spinner to disappear) and then retry to find the next remove buttons?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a request made after you click on remove button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factoring in the spinner is a good way to see when the "internal" process is complete and you can proceed with the next remove action.

But you should wait for the spinner to appear, then disappear. In the test, Cypress will check the spinner very quickly, even before it has appeared.

```js
cy.get('.cart-toggle-btn').click()
cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').each($item => {
  cy.wrap($item).click()
  cy.get('spinner').should('be.visible')       // check visible rather than exists
  cy.get('spinner').should('not.be.visible')
})
```

---

#### With list counter

If you have trouble with the spinner (and don't care about it), check the length of list

If the list re-renders between remove actions, and you get **detached from DOM** errors, re-query the elements inside the loop

```js
cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').each($item => {

  // get fresh count each time
  cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').then($currentList => {  

    const count = $currentList.length   

    cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').first().click()    // remove one 

    // wait for smaller list (when it's not yet empty)
    if (count > 1) {
      cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').should('have.length', count -1)
    } else
      cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').should('not.exist')
    }
  })
})
```

---

#### With conventional Javascript for-loop

This is shorter, using a conventional loop and executing the last remove action outside the loop.

```js
cy.get('.remove.btn').its('length').then(count => {

  for (let index = 1; index < count; index++) {
    cy.get('.remove.btn').first().click()
    cy.get('.remove.btn').should('have.length', count -index)
  }
  cy.get('.remove.btn').first().click()
  cy.get('.remove.btn').should('not.exist')
})
```

Comment: If in snippet 2 I use `get` instead of `contains`, in this way: `cy.contains('.remove.btn').each...` and inside the loop the same, then I get in green: `assertexpected [ <.remove.btn>, 14 more... ] to have a length of 15` but then it fails in red with `cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM. <button type="button" class=".remove.btn">Remove</button>`.

Comment: If I use the 3rd snipped with `get` in the same way I tried for snippet 2 I get in green `assertexpected [ <.remove.btn>, 13 more... ] to have a length of 14` Then in red in one line `get .remove.btn` and next line also red `assert expected [ <.remove-btn>, 12 more... ] to have a length of 14 but got 13` and then it fails with `Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Not enough elements found. Found '13', expected '14'.`

Comment: Hello, snippet 1 (with `contains` exactly as the snipped you posted above) fails with `Assertion Error Timed out retrying after 4000ms: Expected to find element: .spinner, but never found it.` .... snippet 2 and 3 fail with a PASS `assert expected undefined to have a length of 0`

Comment: The spinner approach sounds like a headache. It should be possible to make it work, but maybe it doesn't appear if the action is too quick.

Comment: The last block should get you around the **detached from DOM** error, but the count logic isn't right - it needs to decrease each time through the loop. Will have to adjust it.

Comment: This should now work - it's a bit clunky, I have a feeling there should be a more elegant way.

Comment: wow, yes that's the one. If the cart has some items it works fine now, Thank you!!! I appreciate it. The only problem is that if the cart is already empty, then it fails because it can't find the remove button. FYI the cart empty shows the text "empty". How can I run the above only if the cart is not empty?

Comment: So typically you know how many items are in the cart at the beginning of the test - `Arrange/Act/Assert` in the `Arrage` part you add `n` items to the cart and see if they can be all removed. Cypress doesn't give you many options to check conditionally, but Gleb Bahmutov has a package [cypress-if](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-if) so you can just put it inline `cy.contains('.remove.btn', 'Remove').if().each($item => {...`. But really, don't do it - the better way is to control the test conditions in style of `Arrange/Act/Assert`.